# How can I interrupt the Source Nightmare's water attacks?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

At the beginning of the battle with a giant crab-monster, the Source Nightmare, the characters mention how they have to prevent him from using the nearby water source to power up his attacks. The monster demonstrates what this looks like by sucking up an orb of water to spin around him.

A round or two later, he sucks up 3 more orbs at once. With 4 spinning around him, his water attack is able to one-shot my mages and nearly one-shot my tanks, and hits in an AoE. I've retried the fight by spreading my characters out, but having him just instantly wreck one of my characters is not really my ideal strategy, especially since that character will miss out on XP or force me to waste a lot of time building up action points to revive.

How can I interrupt his water bubbles so his attack isn't so powerful, or else how can I survive his insane damage output?

Comment: Have you tried freezing the water?

Answer (score 1):

I never figured out how to freeze the water, despite having Jahan's chill Aerothurge spell.

But I did find that an Ice elemental soaks the damage nicely. In general, even having a skeleton or fire elemental strategically positioned to be one-shot away from your force takes up enough heat to get in enough of your own whacks.

Comment: you can freeze the water by using other Aerothurge spells. example is the Piercing ice/shard(?)

Comment: So you just target it at the open water? Does that freeze the whole ocean that he draws from? @ken

Comment: i actually don't know, the poor spider queen never got the chance to use it on me. maybe the ones that are created into a water globe?